# Using contours to find where a function can be defined

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I need to find the largest open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ such that the complex holomorphic extension of $f:(0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, given by $f(x) = \log \left( \dfrac{x}{x+1} \right)$, can be defined. I have been asked to do this using contour integration. I know that this is a holomorphic function where it is defined because we can use the logarithm sum property when we extend the real logarithm with the principal branch complex logarithm, giving us $\log \left( \dfrac{z}{z+1} \right) = \log(z) - \log(z+1)$ which are both holomorphic functions on their domains (please correct me if I am wrong with this). I know also that if a continuous function has an antiderivative, then we can use the fundamental theorem of calculus to see that integration over a closed contour over its domain is 0. I am therefore trying to show that the largest domain for this function (with branch cut on the real axis to the left of each logarithms singularities) is the entire complex plane without all negative purely real numbers by showing that a keyhole contour (in this case, an outer arc from $-\alpha$ to $\alpha$ followed by a line at angle $\alpha$ to an inner arc and so on) will give a zero integral because I am assuming that the antiderivative of the logarithm in the real case generalises to the complex case. However, when calculating the integral I am getting real logarithm terms for the arc integrals but they don't appear in the straight line contour integrals, so nothing cancels to give a zero integral before limits are taken. I therefore suspect I am wrong and that this won't actually be zero, but I can not see why. If it isn't, is there any suggestions for a better method to solve this?

Comment: There is a problem with this question because it doesn't specify what is meant by "largest". I.e., largest in what way? Probably the answer being sought is $\Bbb C \setminus [-1,0]$ (yes, that works). Since this is a superset of your idea of throwing out the entire negative numbers, it can truly be considered larger than yours. But it isn't larger or smaller in any measurable way than connecting the two singularities with some other curve, or connecting them both to $\infty$ in other directions.

Comment: Ah yes, I hadn't considered this (and yes, no set containing  my set as a proper subset is the definition of larger. I understand that this can lead to ambiguity when saying 'largest' as you point out that with this definition we can only hope for a 'maximal' set rather than 'maximum'). My main issue with this question, however, is understanding why the integral is not giving zero, or even: should it give zero?

Comment: Your description of the contour you are trying to integrate is too unclear for me to figure out, so I cannot comment on it.Can you give details of the computation you've made?

Comment: Sure. The contour is a piecewise smooth curve created by combining $Re^{it}$ on $[-\alpha,\alpha]$ to a straight line that connects to $re^{-it}$ on $[-\alpha,\alpha]$ that connects via another straight line to the starting point (thus, every complex number on the straight lines have argument $\pm{\alpha}$). I am ending up with terms involving $\log r$ and $\log R$ from the arc integrals but not from the straight line integrals so they do not cancel to zero.